# Make SWT Tree column clip beginning of text

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an SWT Tree (via a JFace TreeViewer), that displays items in columns, some of which have long strings. The end of the string is the meaningful bit for the user, not the start, so when the text is clipped I want the clipping to occur at the start of the string and not the end. Example:

The default behaviour for a cell containing something like: "This is a very long string that completely exceeds the bounds of the tree column" is:

```
|This is a very l...|
```

Where as I want:

```
|... the tree column|
```

**EDIT:**

I solved this with a custom PaintItem listener as described here: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html

Came up with the following code (not quite perfect, some duplication & magic numbers in there):

```
    tree.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, new Listener()
    {
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            String text = ((TreeItem)event.item).getText(event.index);
            Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);
            TreeColumn column = ((Tree)event.widget).getColumn(event.index);                
            int columnWidth = column.getWidth() - 10; /* magic number alert - the cells have some padding - must be a way of determining this... */ 
            if(size.x > columnWidth)
            {
                event.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND;
            }
        }
    });

    tree.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, new Listener()
    {               
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {   
            String text = ((TreeItem)event.item).getText(event.index);
            Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);
            TreeColumn column = ((Tree)event.widget).getColumn(event.index);                
            int columnWidth = column.getWidth() - 10; /* magic number alert - the cells have some padding - must be a way of determining this... */ 
            if(size.x > columnWidth)
            {
                drawTextTail(event, text, columnWidth);
            }                               
        }

        private void drawTextTail(Event event, String text, int columnWidth)
        {
            String clippedText = "";
            int offset = text.length() - 1; 
            String nextClippedText = text.charAt(offset) + clippedText;
            while(fits(nextClippedText, columnWidth, event.gc))
            {
                clippedText = nextClippedText;
                offset--;
                nextClippedText = text.charAt(offset) + clippedText;
            }
            event.gc.drawText("..." + clippedText, 
                    event.x + 5, /* magic number alert - the cells have some padding - must be a way of determining this... */ 
                    event.y, false);
        }

        private boolean fits(String clippedText, int columnWidth, GC gc)
        {
            Point size = gc.textExtent("..." + clippedText);                        
            return size.x < columnWidth;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I had initially said I was using a table - edited to correct that I'm using a tree with columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The second column automatically crops the `String` to fit into the column.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.NONE);
    tree.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);

    TreeColumn column = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.NONE);
    column.pack();
    column.setWidth(100);

    TreeColumn column2 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.NONE);
    column2.pack();
    column2.setWidth(100);

    TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
    item.setText(0, "Baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz");
    item.setText(1, "VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY long text");

    final TextLayout textLayout = new TextLayout(display);

    tree.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            TreeItem item = (TreeItem) event.item;

            Point pt = new Point(event.x + 2, event.y + 2);

            for (int i = 0; i < tree.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                Rectangle rect = item.getBounds(i);

                String text = item.getText(i);

                if (rect.contains(pt)) {
                    String clippedText = "";
                    int offset = text.length() - 1; 
                    int columnWidth = tree.getColumn(i).getWidth();
                    String nextClippedText = text.charAt(offset) + clippedText;
                    while(fits(nextClippedText, columnWidth, event.gc) && offset >= 0)
                    {
                        clippedText = nextClippedText;
                        offset--;
                        if(offset >= 0)
                            nextClippedText = text.charAt(offset) + clippedText;
                    }

                    textLayout.setText(clippedText);

                    textLayout.draw(event.gc, event.x + 3, event.y + 3);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    tree.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            /*
             * indicate that we'll be drawing the foreground in the
             * PaintItem listener
             */
            event.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND;
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
}

private static boolean fits(String clippedText, int columnWidth, GC gc)
{
    Point size = gc.textExtent("..." + clippedText);                        
    return size.x < columnWidth;
}
```

It might need some fixing to really show the `...` in front of the cropped `String`, but it's a start.

Comment: yeah, tried the alignment (incorrectly called it justification in my question) - it alters the alignment fine, but still clips from the start.

Comment: @MalcolmSmith Is this true for the first column or for all columns? Some OS cannot do alignments in the first column. I attached some code to my answer that does what you want for the second column, but not for the first, strangely.

Comment: Yes that is odd. It's happing in the last 2 columns of a 5 column Tree. Also see my bad regarding the original question - I'm using a tree with columns, not a basic table. The alignment changes the alignment for non-overflowing cells, but not the clipping point (start v's end). Also I updated my question with my attempt to use a custom PaintItem listener.

Comment: Do you want to ditch all that stuff about the alignment and I'll accept you answer based on the Paint Listener tip?

Comment: @MalcolmSmith Check my edit. This works for me with the `PaintItem` listener.

Comment: yeah, I think we both got there about the same time... Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a ContentProvider for the TableViewer, right?

In the model that your ContentProvider uses to construct the table, truncate the String yourself.

Comment: That is complicated as the content provider typically doesn't have access to the gc and stuff like that for calculating if truncation is required, and by how much...